# How can I optimize/measure UPSERT performance on MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, database-performance

How can I measure mysql "UPSERT" performance? More specifically, get information about the implied search before the insert/update/replace?

using mysql 8, with a schema that has three fields. Two are part of the primary key. Table is currently innodb but that is not a hard requirement.

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test`.`recent`
( `uid` int NOT NULL, `gid` int NOT NULL, `last` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (`uid`,`gid`),
KEY `idx_last` (`last`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

+----------+----------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
| Field    | Type     | Null | Key | Default           | Extra |
+----------+----------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
| uid      | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL              |       |
| gid      | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL              |       |
| last     | datetime | NO   | MUL | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |       |
+----------+----------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
```

I plan to insert values using

```
INSERT INTO test.recent (uid,gid) VALUES (1, 1) 
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE last=NOW();
```

How do I go about figuring out the performance of this query, since `EXPLAIN` will not show the implied search, only the insert:

```sql
MYSQL> explain INSERT INTO test.recent (uid,gid) VALUES (1, 1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE last=NOW();
+----+-------------+--------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------+
| id | select_type | table  | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra |
+----+-------------+--------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------+
|  1 | INSERT      | recent | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | NULL |     NULL | NULL  |
+----+-------------+--------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MYSQL> explain INSERT INTO test.recent (uid,gid) VALUES (1, 1);
+----+-------------+--------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------+
| id | select_type | table  | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra |
+----+-------------+--------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------+
|  1 | INSERT      | recent | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | NULL |     NULL | NULL  |
+----+-------------+--------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

which is different from the explain on an actual search:

```sql
MYSQL> explain select last from test.recent where uid=1 and gid=1;
+----+-------------+--------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------------+------+----------+-------+
| id | select_type | table  | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref         | rows | filtered | Extra |
+----+-------------+--------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------------+------+----------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | recent | NULL       | const | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 8       | const,const |    1 |   100.00 | NULL  |
+----+-------------+--------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------------+------+----------+-------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

One of the variables I am trying to figure out, is if performance would change at all if I use a blind update instead:

```sql
MYSQL> explain REPLACE INTO test.recent VALUES (1, 1, NOW());
+----+-------------+--------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------+
| id | select_type | table  | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra |
+----+-------------+--------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------+
|  1 | REPLACE     | recent | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | NULL |     NULL | NULL  |
+----+-------------+--------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

But as you can see, the information i get is the same (unhelpful) as I get for an "explain insert".

Another question I would like to answer based on measurements, is if things would change for better or worse (and by how much) If i tested both upserts approaches (on duplicate vs replace) with a `DATE` field (instead of the `DATETIME`), which in theory would results in less writes (but still the same number of implied searches). But again, explain is no help here.

Answer (score 1):

Don't trust `EXPLAIN` with very few rows.

Your IODKU is optimal.  Here's how it will work:

1-. Like a `SELECT`, drill down the `PRIMARY KEY` BTree to find the row with (1,1) or a gap where (1,1) should be.  That is about as fast a lookup as can be had.
2a. If the row exists, `UPDATE` it.
2b. If the row does not exist, `INSERT` (and set `last` to the `DEFAULT` of `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP).

If you want, I can go into details of the steps.  But we are talking sub-millisecond for each.

If I wanted to time the query, I would use some high-res timer.  Very likely the timings would bounce around, depending of whether there is a breeze blowing, or a butterfly is flapping its wings, or the phase of the moon.

Caveat:  If you "simplified" your query for this question, I may not be giving you correct info for the *real* query.

If you are doing a thousand IODKUs, then there may be optimizations that involve combining them.  There are some typical optimizations that can easily give 10x speedup.

Comment: Thanks! The queries/tables are slightly simplified, but nothing dramatic. I do expect about 2k qps (90% updates) on peaks or thereabouts. When you say combining them you mean sending several updates on the same transaction or something else?

Comment: @gcb - Updates are hard to combine; Inserts speed up a lot.